# Issue using tinymce editor

Tags: php, tinymce

I'm using tinymce as my website's text editor.

Whenever I try to add content using it, it works perfectly, but if theres a
`'` inside the text ( for example : "Can't" ) I get the following error :

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '...
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with tinymce. If you remove tinymce and add a simple text box you will have the same outcome. You need to escape user input before trying to store it in the database. Even better: Give PDO a try and use prepared statements.

Comment: Editors like tinymce are susceptible to XSS attacks. You should also be using something like [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) on the server side to clean up the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using Prepared Statements. This means that special characters such as ' will interfere with your SQL statements. Ultimately, this means that your code is open to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Look into using Prepared Statements with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Here's a simple example from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php):

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>
```